# Password is not matching for my PHP login form

Tags: php, pdo

I have tried many times but every time its says `Email & Password Not Matched!`.I can not find any solution of it.I have used **PDO** for database connection.I think i have problem with session value.But i can not find the error.I have tried so far:

```
<?php
/* For Login */

include 'db.php';
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $hash  = $_POST['password'];
    $password  = password_hash($hash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $records = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?");
    $records->execute(array($email,$password));
    $userdata = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!empty($email) && !empty($hash)) {
        if (count($userdata)>0 ) {
            //session_start();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $userdata['email'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $userdata['password'];
            if ($_POST['password'] == $userdata['password']) {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-success text-center'>
                      <strong>Successfully</strong> Login</div>";
                exit;
            }else{
                echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'> 
                      <strong>Email & Password</strong> Not Matched!
                      </div>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Email and Password Not Matched!";
            echo $_SESSION['email'];
        }
    }else{
        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'>
              <strong>Email & Password</strong> must not be empty!</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check in your database you store raw password or encrypted password

Comment: my database have hashed password.

Comment: check password_hash function generate same password which store in database

Comment: you making the the conditions that never be true  $_POST['password'] == $userdata['password'] 
use $password== $userdata['password']

Comment: @DhavalPurohit same message showing again.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud see what you does in the query.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud  you only select the id in the query
then how $userdata['email'] and $userdata['password'] having the value from the database.?

Comment: try with SELECT id,email,password FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?

and condition with 
$password== $userdata['password'] 

this will surely work

Comment: @DhavalPurohit not working same message again.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud are you getting the result from query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are re hashing the incoming password, that is not how its done with `password_hash()` you need to use `password_verify()` to test that the hashed password on the database in the same as the plain text password passed in by the user.

If you run `password_hash()` using the same password twice in a row you will get a different hash each time, therefore you must use `password_verify()` to verify the entered password against the hashed one on the database.

Try this from the CLI and it will demonstrate:

```
$password = 'WoopsADaisy';
echo password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT).PHP_EOL;
echo password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT).PHP_EOL;
```

The output, only when I ran it as a test returns

```
$2y$10$t52UeqDlP897iD/n6uo71OErIFP5c4wsli6gLRNdfyQLkv8m6Wxs2
$2y$10$FczpgQIsmpzr6.vhYA6d3.QmEe3i3HR4WkapLrtO/BLK4Uul0WjUa
```

You wont get the same hashes, but you will get 2 different hashes!

This also means you need to mod your process a little

```
<?php
/* For Login */

// always start the session at the top of a script
session_start();

include 'db.php';

// isset can test many variables at the same time
if (isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])) {
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $plain_pwd  = $_POST['password'];

    // get hashed password to test
    // also you were never actually retrieving the email
    $records = $db->prepare("SELECT id,password,email 
                             FROM users WHERE email=?");
    $staus = $records->execute(array($email));

    // test the query actually worked
    if ( $staus === false ) {
        print_r($db->errorInfo());
        exit;
    }

    $userdata = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



    if ( password_verify($plain_pwd, $userdata['password']) ) {
        // the entered password is GOOD

        $_SESSION['email'] = $userdata['email'];

        // never need to store in session
        //$_SESSION['password'] = $userdata['password'];

        echo "<div class='alert alert-success text-center'>
              <strong>Successfully</strong> Login</div>";
    } else {
        echo "Email and Password do not Match!";
    }

}else{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'>
          <strong>Email & Password</strong> must not be empty!</div>";
}
?>
```

> Something else that can trip you up when hashing passswords. Make sure that the column `password` on your table is long enough to hold the hashed password. 60 chars in what `password_hash()` created using `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` but as the default hash algorithm may change over time should it need strengthening, it is recommended to make this column a varchar(255) to keep your database future proof.
>
> References :
>
> [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passwordhash.php)
>
> [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Perfect explanation.I understand.Thanks : )